# Can't align view to the right

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to display one view in the left side and one to the right side of the parent layout as following:

```
<LinearLayout     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But as a result I see both textViews aligned to the left only. I don't understand why. I manage to set the verticaly layout_gravity but not the horizontal one. In addition, I could add:

```
android:gravity="right"
```

to the parent layout and than see both views on the right side but couldnt find a way to display one in the left side and one in the right side.
Please help.

Comment: Use for relative layout

Comment: Have you tried using layout weights?

Comment: The problem with layout wights is they split the `LinearLayout` in fixed ratio. Using a `RelativeLayout` seems the cleanest solution, using the one I suggested in my answer would be the computationally fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another trick here;

Place an invisible `View` between the `TextView`s. And it will occupy the whole remaining area with `android:layout_weight="1"`, so `TextView`s will remain on both ends. No gravity needed. Try the code below :)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's the best solution for me. Mainly because in my real case I have got actually 3 views and I need to align 1 to the left and 2,3 to the right. and the place holder view is the only thing that could solve this.

Comment: Thanks. Yes gravity solutions are more complicated, placeholder is simple for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="left" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Or Try the following

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit:**
In method 1 using weight for splitting the total screen as two parts and set the gravity for first item is left and gravity for second item is right.
I am not using  android:layout_gravity for TextView . Using android:gravity. Better practise you can use relativeLayout. Check the second option

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_weight="1"` to both your TextViews

Answer (score 0):

Use Relativelayout instead

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left"
       android:gravity="left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="right"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="right" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Someone please explain what's wrong with this code? Specially who voted down this..

Comment: Although it is a working solution, this is probably the worst way to solve the issue, because it introduces unnecessary nesting of layouts. Do this only if you want your app to be the least efficient possible.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution with `LinearLayout` is modifying your right textview with `gravity="right"`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="right"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

But I would strongly reccomend using a `RelativeLayout` as @Sjd suggested.